# Inserting some data from one table into another table

Tags: sql-server

I am going to populate an intersection table with a value from another table (view), but I have one value which will be static for each insert.

My query looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.intersectiontable
(col1, col2)
SELECT *col3*, col4
FROM dbo.viewtable
WHERE *col3* is null
```

Now, *col3* is the field that I need to switch out with a static value (eg. 11), how can I both insert from another table AND specify one static value?

My guess would be

```
INSERT INTO dbo.intersectiontable
(col1, col2)
VALUES
(11, (SELECT col4 FROM dbo.viewtable WHERE col3 is null))
```

But to me that doesn't quite look right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this...

```
INSERT INTO dbo.intersectiontable
(col1, col2)
SELECT 11, col4 FROM dbo.viewtable WHERE col3 is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.intersectiontable (col1, col2) VALUES 
(SELECT 11, col4 FROM dbo.viewtable WHERE col3 is null)
```

Comment: @NichlasTorgersen No it doesn't. This is not correct syntax. The `VALUES` followed by `(SELECT 11, col4`

Comment: You're right, but atleast he was close! The basics are there, and that's pretty much what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

INSERT INTO dbo.intersectiontable(col1, col2) SELECT 11,col4 FROM dbo.viewtable WHERE col3 is null